# jQuery Navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side navigation bar that uses jQuery to pull hidden divs to the screen.  I want to each `<li>` on the side bar to get the active class when it is clicked.

I'm trying to get it to say on click of `<li>` give the active class to the `<li>` and then on click of the next `<li>` remove the active class and automatically give it to the next clicked `<li>`.

My current method isn't working very well.  Below is my HTML and Script:

```
<ul>
    <li id="overview" class="selector"><a href="#">OVERVIEW</a></li>
    <li id="whyus" class="selector"><a href="#">WHY US</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery("#overviewHidden").fadeIn();
jQuery("li#overview").addClass('active');

jQuery("#overview").click(function () {
    jQuery('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery("li#overview").addClass('active');
    jQuery('#whyusHidden, #clientsHidden, #staffHidden').hide();
    jQuery('#overviewHidden').slideDown();
});

jQuery("#whyus").click(function () {
    jQuery('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery("li#whyus").addClass('active');
    jQuery('#overviewHidden, #clientsHidden, #staffHidden').hide();
    jQuery('#whyusHidden').slideDown();
});
</script>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var activeitem;

$(document).ready(function () {
  var items = $("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function () {
      if (activeitem) {
        activeitem.removeClass("active");
      }
      activeitem = $(this);
      activeitem.addClass("active");
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work for me.  I added a class to each list item.  I'm going to need a way to tie it into what div content I load for the next project. I think on click of .selector I need to give active class to whatever li i clicked, then on next click remove the class from the previous li and give it to the next one.

Comment: @user2445613 there was a typo in the code `lentgh` I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("li.selector").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```